# Move cursor to placeholder element in a contentEditable DIV

Tags: javascript, html, selection, contenteditable, textrange

I have a contentEditable DIV and, when the user presses a key, the underlying code is processed and replaced by updated code.  Alas, this causes the cursor position to be lost.

However, in order to preserve the cursor position, I am successfully inserting a `<span id="placeholder"></span>` into the DIV at the correct position before processing begins.  This preserves the cursor's intended position, but now I can't seem to set the range to select it.

Here's what I currently have:

```
function focusOnPlaceholder() {

    var placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');

    if( !placeholder ) return;

    var sel, range;

    if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {                    
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(placeholder);
        range.collapse(true);
        sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(placeholder);
        range.select();
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated, and a cross-browser solution would be incredible :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cross-browser solution would be to use my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) library and specifically the [selection save/restore module](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/SelectionSaveRestoreModule), which uses a similar placeholder technique and is well tested. However, this can probably be fixed without using a library by putting some content (for example, a non-breaking space (`\u00A0` or `&nbsp;` in HTML) inside your placeholder element. You may want to remove the placeholder in `focusOnPlaceholder()` after selecting the range.

Comment: The non-breaking space addition did the trick.  Going to look into Rangy now.  Thanks!